# Camera 2 Api, how to take a photo / set of photos without locking the preview?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2

When using captureBurst or capture, the preview is blocked, is there an opportunity to take a photo (preferably not one) and not block the preview?

Comment: Depends on the resolution you are ready to compromise on, and not all devices are born equal.

Comment: The bigger, the better. But cupture and cuptureBurst have a shutter lag time of 400 ms.
In the standard android camera there is a burst shoot function, with a long press, frames are saved in series. How it is implemented and whether it can be done with the help of the api camera. The frame from the preview does not suit, you need frames in the highest possible quality and resolution.

Comment: The shutter lag depends on device. Some have ZSL mode that really works, others only cheat that they support ZSL.

Comment: There is no ZSL on the phone on which I am doing the tests, but there is a serial shooting in the standard camera, it does not block the preview. I want to achieve this in my application.